# How did the Trojan allies get to Troy?

Tags: ancient-history

Also, across which territory did they pass? From which side of the world did  they come?

Comment: To avoid obvious answers, you should take a look at the [Trojan Catalogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Battle_Order) article on Wikipedia and update your question to tell us what more you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Trojan war is known to us really only through Homer. His epic poems are more works of mythology than history. So the events of Homer's war are not really  historical facts that can be reasoned about in this way.

We can fairly reasonably trust some of the basic facts Homer presented though. For instance, here's a map of Bronze Age Greece, with place names given by Homer.
[image]

One thing you may notice immediately is pretty much every place is on the coast. There's a reason for that. Boat was by far the fastest means of travel at the time, but even by the standards of the day, Greek society was maritime-based. Particularly in Anatolia, the powerful Hittite Empire controlled the interior, but anywhere a boat could reach in this area was instead Greek.

Troy, where the map-makers have placed it, is also a coastal city. So it frankly wouldn't have made much sense for anyone who ever attacked it, barring neighbors who share a border (or the Hittites) to have arrived any other way than by boat.

In fact, the part of the Illiad all these place names are taken from is called the [Catalog of **Ships**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalogue_of_Ships)<sup>*</sup>. According to that work this was accomplished with a fleet of over a thousand ships arriving from 29 different places.

<sup>* - This is considered by some to be a later work, tacked onto Homer's</sup>

Comment: I want to help you,- only Percotes came with a boats,others came "go on foot".Paeonians travelled 12 days, Homer never says they passed across the sea .Thracians came with horses,without boats,but how?